# Visual Studio: Add necessary using directives with macro

Tags: visual-studio, macros

I am trying to do the following. Imagine you are reading some LINQ article and you decide to copy/paste some code from the article to a newly created project. In most cases, if you directly compile you will probably get an error for missing a using directives or assembly reference. I am trying to optimize the process where I have to go each keyword, click on it with the mouse and hit Shift + Alt + F10 to add the using directive. I know that it is not that much pain, but for the sake of optimization, is it possible and at what cost?

Best Regards,

Kiril

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resharper can also automate this process for you, but it has a [price](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/buy/index.jsp)

Answer (score -1):

You can use Ctrl + .

It's 50% faster than Shift+Alt+F10